# Ektron 9 - How to set Page Title (<html><head><title>...</title>...)

Tags: ektron

Noob question, but google is not giving me the goods:

How do you set the page title in a page in Ektron 9? You know: the text that goes into the `title` tag in the `head` of the html document.

In an Ektron 8 site I have used, there was a page title meta value that was used.

- Does this work out-of-the-box?
- If not, are there best practices?

#### What I have tried

- Title of page is the "Content Title" not "Page Title"
- New page widget does not have "page title" on alias screen as one pdf suggested
- Googling "ektron page title" and variants did not throw up much.
- Editing ektron page's folder properties did not show up anything.
- Ektron settings "metadata definitions" does not have one for page title

Will keep you posted if I find the answer myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ektron does not create the definitions for Title, Description, Keywords or other SEO-related metadata out of the box (when you set up a min site, as is standard).

The site manager / developer defines those. How you set that on the page depends on your implementation and Ektron version.

For example, most 8.0 (and prior) sites will use the CMS:Metadata control in the  of the master page (or page, if no master). The control accepts one dynamic parameter, so I used to place three controls, one for content (dynamic param = id), for forms (dynamic param = ekfrm), and for PageBuilder (dynamic param = pageid).

It's more common now (versions 8.5+) to see developers retrieving the metadata from the content (whether html / smart form, html form, or pagebuilder) using the ContentManager API method GetItem. This method accepts two params - the first is the ID of the item you want to retrieve, the second is boolean and, when set to true, will tell the API to retrieve metadata values. Once you have the values, you define the output.

Either method will work in versions 8.5+. The latter gives you more control.

Comment: Once again thank you ... I'll try to keep quiet for a while now ;)

Comment: Though I would question that `title` is mainly SEO related, yes it is important, but more important for basic page UX.

Comment: I happen to agree. Either way, it's not an out-of-the-box definition. I'd say a good portion of people just use the content title as the Title of the page (we don't because our marketing team sees it as differently strategic). That segmentation of source is the most likely reason for omission of the separate title metadata definition.

Comment: I believe the Metadata control will allow you to pass multiple parameter names into "DynamicParameter" like so DynamicParameter="id,pageid,ekfrm".  That way you can have 1 Metadata control to cover all page types.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ektron 9 SP2.

We have a single line in the master page:

We use the DefaultContentID of the PageBuilder wireframe that is the front page.  The other aspx templates just get the metadata of the HTML content item - all of our non-pagebuilder pages have a content block, then a bunch of smartform data.